# tkagg backend problems

Tags: matplotlib

I need to use the Tkagg backent to use matplotlib in a Tkinter program, and I received the "ImportError: No module named backend_tkagg" error message.

Looking around, I saw as one possible solution that I add to install the agg-dev libs, so I did (Fedora fc13 here): *yum install agg agg-devel*
... but the problem persisted.

I thought that maybe I had to reinstall matplotlib, so I issued a *easy_install -m matplotlib*, but no luck (though the same error message seems to come from a different file now, namely /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/**init**.py )

any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by compiling `matplotlib` from source. It has Tkagg active by default.
Only problem was it didn't compile Tkagg since I didn't have tk-devel installed... after installing it everything went ok.

So I still don't know if `easy_install matplotlib` doesn't use TkAgg by design, or if it too checked and noticed that I didn't have `Tk.h` installed, but anyway this is the way to go.

Comment: Nice work! Thanks for answering your own post.  It seems this problem pops up every 2 years.  I installed matplotlib with pip install matplotlib so i did: $sudo pip uninstall matplotlib.  $sudo pip install matplotlib  and voila!

Comment: Note: you may need to install a few packages (tcl, tcl-devel, tk, tk-devel, agg and agg-devel) from your package manager to get tkagg backend setup to build Matplotlib in Linux.

Comment: @Pete,it would be helpful if you could share the command to install those as the standard sudo apt-get doesnt seem to work!

Comment: @darKoram,it worked for me,thanks for sharing....but i would ask if there is a way to install to install it with pip without using the sudo mode....because i keep changing environment and some of them i dont root access to install them!

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan: `sudo yum install tcl tcl-devel tk tk-devel agg agg-devel` on CentOS/Fedora/RHEL based machines.

Comment: @Pete,that would require to have root access(sudo) which i dont have! ,on my local mahcine ,when i use sudo i can plot without problem in my virtualenv...but it fails(ploting) when i run the script without sudo showing my backend to be agg only instead of tkagg which eventually works well when i use sudo

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue today.

By default, Tkagg was not available for me (Ubuntu 14.04), so I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev libpng-dev libffi-dev dvipng texlive-latex-base
```

Then uninstalled and reinstalled matplotlib:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: tested under arch linux, installing tk and reinstall matplotlib solves the problem

Comment: Quick comment (OpenSuse) - I had to use pip --no-cache-dir install matplotlib, as without the --no-cache-dir flag pip assumes tkinter is still missing and doesn't bother checking again. There's 5 hours of my life I'll never get back!

Comment: @Alex Thank you for posting that comment. Fixed my problem.

Comment: I had to go a step further and use the nuclear option of just wiping out my entire virtual environment and reinstalling it (Arch)