# Error using tkagg backend

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.5

I am using the following setup:

```
Python 3.5.2 + Matplotlib 1.5.x (Raspberry Pi)
```

I have added `backend :tkagg` to my rc file.

If I run `get_backend()` it returns `"tkagg"`

However, when I try to import `matplotlib` as follows:

```
 Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
 [GCC 4.9.1] on linux
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

 >>> import matplotlib as mpl
 >>> mpl.use('tkagg')
 >>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I receive the following traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 13, in <module>
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib-1.5.0-py3.4-linux-armv7l.egg/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 9, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends import _tkagg
 ImportError: cannot import name '_tkagg'
```

Why isn't `matplotlib` being imported correctly?

Comment: Did you have an actual question?

Comment: @MattDMo, Yes,  why isn't Matplotlib producing graphs?

Comment: Thanks for reformating my problem, i'll do better next time. DJ

Comment: One other note,  I also tried deleting the Matplotlib cache, from .cache.

Comment: Do you have Tkinter installed?

Comment: @Mike Müller, there is a tkinter directory ( /usr/lib/python3.4) but no "tkinter" program?

Comment: One other note, Python2.7 is also installed and Matplotlib and it produces graphs just find???

Answer (score 1):

I basicly follow the instruction in this post:
[tkagg backend problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933335/tkagg-backend-problems?rq=1)

Then  used git to get the source:
sudo git clone git://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.git

Then did build/install using Python3.4:
sudo python3.4 setup.py install