# Matplotlib plot window is black

Tags: python, matplotlib

I recently started studying python and matplotlib. The problem I face is that I always get a black window as a plot output.

See simple code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab


x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

#plot the x and y and you are supposed to see a sine curve
plt.plot(x, y)

pylab.show()
```

[image: screenshot]

I get the same result executing code samples from matplotlib pages.
Does anyone have any idea where this comes from and how to overcome this?

I'm using the Operating system Linux Mint.

Comment: Sorry ! Operating system Linx Mint

Comment: Actually the use of pylab is discouraged, so try plt.show() instead, maybe it'll help? http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related

Comment: Same result, black window.

Comment: Can you try to get matplotlib.get_backend() in python shell? You may miss some libraries. See http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/08/24/resolved-matplotlib-figures-not-showing-up-or-displaying/

Comment: executing  matplotlib.get_backend()  output 'TkAgg'

Comment: @Robert What happens if you execute `import _tkinter` in shell? If it works, try another steps from [Checking your Tkinter support](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

Comment: import Tkinter in Shell works. I tried Tkinter._test() works too

Comment: @Robert I'd probably reinstall `Tkinter` and `matplotlib`. There are some issues with `TkAgg` on Unix systems according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933335/tkagg-backend-problems). Another approach is to try to change your [backend](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend).

Answer (score 1):

I executed code in python shell and it works, the problem comes executing code in python editors. I worked with two different editors.

[image]

Best regards

Robert

Comment: Which editors were you using?